# table cell accessory uncenters my label with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift

[image: screenshot depicting misalignement]

[constraints picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09lM8.png)

The row where I add a '>' accessory becomes uncentered compared to all my other labels. I added the accessory programatically. Any way around this? I am coding in Swift

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     // some code stuff
    // switch case..

    case 6:
        cell.cellID             = "age"
        cell.labelRowTitle.text = "Ålder"
    case 7:
        cell.cellID             = "jobRole"
        cell.labelRowTitle.text = "Yrke"
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator

    default: print("WARNING: Default in switch in tableview")
    }        
    return cell
}
```

Comment: How did you set your constraints ?

Comment: Can you show the code where are you adding the Label and accessory ?

Comment: label is added in storyboard, you can see that in the second screen shot. Accessory is added in programatically